# How to pull out data from a javascript object with key assigned as "*"?

Tags: javascript, object

I am using wikipedia api to get some data from them I am getting data response in this manner.

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "continue": {
        "accontinue": "WYSIWYG_extensions/da",
        "continue": "-||"
    },
    "query": {
        "allcategories": [
            {
                "size": 1,
                "pages": 1,
                "files": 0,
                "subcats": 0,
                "*": "WikibaseRepoEntityTypes extensions/ar"
            },
            {
                "size": 5,
                "pages": 5,
                "files": 0,
                "subcats": 0,
                "*": "WikibaseRepoEntityTypes extensions"
            },
```

i want to get the data from "*" key from the objects that I am getting back but i am not able to my IDE sees it as a problem. What should I do?[image: This the way my IDE is seeing it]

Answer (score 1):

You can try `console.log(resp.query.allcategories[0]['*']);`

This is [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)

Answer (score 1):

Try to access it like this

```
console.log(resp.query.allcategories[0]['*']);
```

It should work
please refer this for more info
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation